# sitecore Copy bucket item issue

Tags: sitecore8

Issue with the copy functionality.

When I try to copy any bucket item to another item(bucket or non bucket item) on selection of item in content tree it works fine.
But when the same has been attempted by mentioning the path of destination folder in path field of “Copy item to dialog box” it creates a copy in the same parent.

Please follow below mentioned steps to recreate the scenario mentioned above.

1. Right click on the item to be copied.
2. EDIT the path field with desired destination field and click copy button.
3. Item is created under the same parent though path mentioned in the Path field was different

Note: If the case is like we have to select item in the content tree, and mentioning the path in the path field is of no use, Can I get a patch where path field is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Bucketed items loose their parent-child relation. To put simply, programatically, we cannot find the parent of a bucketed item. This is not an answer to your question but it can help to investigate further. If 'Copy To' functionality using 'Path' field needs to know the parent of current item, then it will not work in case of bucketed item. In worst case it may end up creating a duplicate of the item in same hierarchy.